# Math in picture environment

Tags: math-mode, diagrams

Is it possible to avoid excessive use of the symbol `$` in pictures 
containing a lot of formulas/math symbols? I mean to use
`\put(m,n}{math}` instead of `\put(m,n}{$math$}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 7):

You may define a new command:

```
\documentclass{article}

% define new command that includes the $ signs
\def\mput(#1)#2{\put(#1){$#2$}}

\begin{document}
    %example
    \begin{picture}(10,10)
        \put(0,10){$a^1$}
        \mput(0,0){a^2}
    \end{picture}


\end{document}
```

result:

[image: result 1]

If you would like to replace the put command you can do this

```
\documentclass{article}

%let \putOld be the same definition as \put
\let\putOld\put
%use \putOld to redefine the original put command
\def\put(#1)#2{\putOld(#1){$#2$}}

\begin{document}
    %example
    \begin{picture}(10,10)
        \putOld(0,10){$a^1$}
        \put(0,0){a^2}
    \end{picture}


\end{document}
```

result:

[image: result 2]